# Duplicate data vs Calculated data in database

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-normalization

I'm starting to track a host of variables around my life (QuantifiedSelf).  I have a lot of input sources, and I'm working on sticking it all into a database.  I plan on using this database with R to ask arbitrary questions about my life ("Which routes are the fastest to work", or "What foods affect my mood", etc)

The key question I'm trying to answer here is **"Do I process the input before sticking it into the database?"**

Examples of "process":

1. Some of my input is a list of moods (one for each day).  As of right now, there are only 5 available moods (name with a rating between -2 and 2).  Do I normalize this data and create two tables:  A Mood table (with 5 items) and a DailyMood table?

   - If I process the data then I lose the original data.  Perhaps I change a mood to have a different name.  If I do this in a normalized database, then I lose the information that before the change, I had a mood "oldName"
   - If I don't process the data, then I have duplication of data
2. Another input is a list of GPS locations (lat, long).  However, most of my day is spent in a single spot, or spent driving.  Do I process this data to create two tables "Locations" and "Routes"?

   - If I don't process the data, then I have a whole bunch of duplicate locations (at different timestamps), which is difficult to query and get good data out of.
   - If I process the data, then I lose the original data.  I end up with a nice set of Locations and Routes that is easy to query, but if those locations or routes are wrong, I would have to redownload the input source and rebuild the database.

However, I feel like I'm stuck between two opposing "ideals":

1. If I process the data, then I don't have the original data.
2. If I don't process the data, then I have duplicate, hard to use data.

I've considered storing both the original and the calculated.  This feels like I'm getting the worst of both worlds:  Some of my tables aren't original, and would need a full recalculation if they are wrong, while other tables are original but hard to use and have duplicate data.

Comment: You need to ask yourself the question behind the statement: "I'm working on sticking it all into a database." Why? Why are your sticking it into a database? Is it to keep an archive? Is it to run new reports on it? Is it to built your own version of QuantifiedSelf? In your answer to "why" lies the seed to answer your other questions as to how you should normalize and structure your own (imported) data.

Comment: Ah, good question.  I'm sticking in a database to make run reports.  I want to use it as an input source for R so I can ask arbitrary questions about my life.  I'll add that to my post.

Comment: R deals with data specifics to provide weighted values that can be used for predictive analytics. For example, does your mood (-2 to +2) and your GPS location (or variance of) correlate? If your data types change, your prior weights don't have merit. You'll need to calculate a new set of weights. This is not a bad thing. You should be recalculating your weights regularly to identify long-term cycles. If the calculated value has merit on its own, keep it. In past enterprise apps that I worked on, we even kept both calc and raw data.

Answer (score 0):

To some of the points in the comments, I think which data you store depend on the need in your application, and I would approach each set of data through a use case lens.

For the first use case, mood data, it sounds like there is value in being able to see this data over time (i.e. it appears that over the last month, my mood has been improving) as well as to pull up individual events (i.e. on date x, I ate a hamburger, how did this affect my mood in the subsequent mood entry after date x).

If it were me, I would create a Mood table, with two attributes:

- Name
- Id (pk)

This table would essentially serve as a definition table. Here you could add attributes specific to the mood (such as description).

I would then create a MoodHistory table with the following attributes:
- Timestamp
- MoodId
- IsCurrent (Boolean)

Before you enter a mood in your application, UPDATE MoodHistory SET IsCurrent = 0 WHERE IsCurrent = 1, and then insert your new record with IsCurrent = 1. This structure is normalized and by indexing or partitioning by the IsCurrent column (and honestly even without any indexing/partitioning), even as your table grows quite large, you should always be able to query the current mood super quickly.

For your second use case, this is quite dependent not only on your planned usage, but where the data is coming from (particularly for routes). I'm not sure how you are planning on grouping locations into "routes" but if you clarify in the comments, I'm happy to add to my answer.

For locations however, I'm assuming you're taking a Location Snapshot during some set time interval. I would create a LocationSnapshot table structured similarly to the MoodHistory table:

I would then create a MoodHistory table with the following attributes:

- Timestamp
- Latitude
- Longitude
- IsCurrent
  By processing your IsCurrent data in a similar way to your MoodHistory data, it should be quite straightforward to grab the last entered location. You could also do some additional processing if you want to avoid duplicates. Essentially, before updating IsCurrent, query the row where IsCurrent = 1. Then compare that records Latitude and Longitude to your new Latitude and Longitude before Inserting the new record. If there is any change, proceed to the insert, otherwise, no need to insert a new record.

You could also create a table of known locations such as KnownLocation:

- Latitude
- Longitude
- Name

Joining to this table ON Latitude and Longitude should tell you when you were spending time at a particular location, say "Home" vs "Work"

Comment: Grouping locations into routes simply means making an ordered list of points.  Google's Map API actually has a Snap to Roads API that does just this.

Comment: That said, this doesn't quite answer my question.  For example, when I compare my new Latitude/Longitude to my new Latitude/Longitude, chances are, they are different, even if I haven't moved.  There's always a little bit of variance in location.  This is solvable:  Check if I have moved more than X meters.  However, now I've got a variable X.  If I make X too small, my data is less useful.  If I make X too big, I've lost data.  This is core problem I'm running into:  Useful, queryable data vs data loss.

Comment: I think how big you make x is more of a question of what data you want to store, rather than how it's stored. Happy to clarify any points/questions around how the data should be stored but don't have much to offer in terms of what data to store. That will be dependent on how you want to use the data

Comment: Right, that's kind of my point.  My question isn't about "What should be the schema of my database?", but rather "Should I process data before?"